# Formatting a field in Excel with vba in the number format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to format a field with VBA to a Number with 2 decimal places and a 1000 separator. Is this possible via VBA?

Comment: Do the same thing while recording a macro and get the code ready in the module

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Macro Recorder - that will give you what you're after.

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```